# Fresh install of Ubuntu cannot connect to internet

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet

I am running Windows 10 and I want to run Ubuntu in a dual boot setup.
I have followed the advice on [the ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to create a bootable USD stick. I have tried 16.04.2 LTS and 17.04.

FYI: I am a complete noob to Linux of any sort, but I do know my way around a (Windows) computer.

For both of them the symptom is the same. It detects that a wired connection is available but does not really connect. I say not really, because sometimes I can get it to connect but I only see ipv6 details on the connection info, however Firefox does not work. I also tried manually entering the ipv4 details (fixed ip address etc) but that did not work either.

My hardware definitely works because I am writing this message on the same machine (in Windows) without touching the cable or the router. Any advice would be appreciated. I do know how to enter commands into the terminal if you need me to, provided you tell me what command to use.

*******************UPDATE

as requested, what follows is the results of the terminal commands.
As I did not have an internet connection, I had to copy the output to the Libreoffice version of word, save it to disk, start up as windows and then paste it to here. In the process, the resulting txt files came out as single line files so I will try to put line returns where I think they belong, but if it looks weird, that is why.

**ifconfig**

```
eno1      
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:90:96:db:8a:98  

inet6 addr: fe80::e116:9d0d:110c:e4d6/64 Scope:Link

inet6 addr: 2001:8f8:1127:147:2ac8:4f10:2ee5:db16/64 Scope:Global

UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

RX packets:799 errors:0 dropped:34 overruns:0 frame:0

TX packets:412 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

RX bytes:147392 (147.3 KB)  TX bytes:43192 (43.1 KB)

Interrupt:20 Memory:f7100000-f7120000 

lo        
Link encap:Local Loopback  

inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1

RX packets:671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

TX packets:671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 

RX bytes:53584 (53.5 KB)  TX bytes:53584 (53.5 KB)


**lspci**

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2001 PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge

**cat**

interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) auto lo iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: You didn't specify any advanced information (possibly) needed for succesful fix of your problem. Could you, please, open the terminal and put in these commands (without quotes), pressing enter after each one, and post the output of them? The commands are: "lspci", "ifconfig" and "cat /etc/network/interfaces".

Comment: It's not going to be easy as I don't an internet connection. Give me 10 minutes

Comment: Is this a wired or wireless connection problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with seems to be a lack of an IP address. Open up a terminal and write in (without quotes) "sudo dhclient eno1". Try if your internet connection works. If it does, you can change the /etc/network/interfaces file to do this automatically. If you want to do that, run (no quotes, again) "sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces". Since you are doing an administrative task, you may be prompted for your password. You'll notice that the terminal became a text editor. Go down to the end of the file and add enough line breaks to have a blank line between what was in the file and what you are about to put in. Then, write

allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

on two lines in the file.
Then press CTRL+O to save the changes and CTRL+X to close.
Detailed breakdown:
allow-hotplug eno1  -run this when you see a hotplug event on device eno1 
iface eno1 inet dhcp     -on interface eno1, in ipv4 rules, get an address from DHCP

Comment: I got in touch with a friend who works with Linux systems. He gave me some commands to run which disable ipv6. I then restarted the machine and then it worked. I also tinkered with some other stuff so I am not certain that the solution was to disable ipv6. In any case it works now but I want to do a clean install once I figure out how to get CUDA and tensorflow up and running. Once I do a fresh install, I will try your solution and if it works, accept it as the answer. If not, I will try the ipv6 disable thing and if that works, post it as the answer.

Comment: Note that the solution is only needed if you can't see the eno1 in the /etc/network/interfaces file. Also, make sure to run "ifconfig -a" again after the reinstall to see if eno1 changed to something else.